Where can I find the algorithm that Blender uses for dynamic elements (physics)?
I need algorithms like DEM, IBD, MSS, SPH.
I know these are used, but where can I find more about them? My thesis is about comparing these elements in Blender and Houdini, but I need a site where I can discuss these things. Thank you.

For rigid bodies Blender uses the Bullet3 physics engine:
https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3
